# How to pause and reset all on-going song when other song is clicked?

Tags: java, android, pause

I have made a music app which has only 4-5 songs stored locally in data folder.

I have separate buttons [CardViews] for each songs.
But when a song is playing and i click another song's cardview, both songs start playing simultaneously. How do i stop the previous one.

Here is my code but this is too lengthy when i have more than 5 songs and also gives me some errors. I dont want any listview that fetches all songs.

```
    final MediaPlayer music1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music1);
    final MediaPlayer music2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music2);
    final MediaPlayer music 3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music3);
```

HERE's how i do it now !!

```
cardMusic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (music2.isPlaying()
                        || music3.isPlaying()) {

                    music1.start();
                    music2.pause();
                    music3.pause();


                    crntSongPlaying.setText("Music1");

                    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled_white);
                } else {
                    music1.start();
                    crntSongPlaying.setText("Music1");
                    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled_white);

                }
            }
        });
```

The app does works but misbehaves as mentioned above sometimes. and the code is too lengthy.. any way that i could pause and reset all already playing mediaplayers..??

here's the error i get sometimes..

```
I/chatty: uid=10643(com.myapps.musicplayer2) identical 5 lines
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9d277be0)
    error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative: pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9d276a20)
    error (-38, 0)
    pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9d276ba0)
    error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative: pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9d276d60)
    error (-38, 0)
    pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9d276de0)
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
    pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9d276e60)
    error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative: pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9d276ec0)
    error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
I/chatty: uid=10643(com.myapps.musicplayer2) identical 5 lines
```

Comment: Can you create 1 MediaPlayer and replace it with other songs?

Comment: Sanjeev how do i do so?

Answer (score 0):

to reset other songs use the stop() method and assign null to Mediaplayer instance.and reassign the song.
I modified your code, try this

```
MediaPlayer music1;
MediaPlayer music2 ;
MediaPlayer music3 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     music1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music1);
     music2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music2);
     music3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music3);

     cardMusic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (music2 != null && music2.isPlaying()) {
                //to reset the song first stop it and then assign null to MediaPlayer 
                music2.stop();
                music2 = null;
                //reaasign the song because mediaplayer is null. 
                music2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music2);

            } else if (music3 != null && music3.isPlaying()) {
                music3.stop();
                music3 = null;
                music3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music2);

            } else if (music1!=null){
                music1.start();

                crntSongPlaying.setText("Music1");
                playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled_white);
            }

    }
});
```

}

let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: It looks slightly neat than mine but still i have around 8-9 songs now so a lots of ELSE IF statements .. any shorter method .?? I'll use your method until then..